# Finding files with square brackets in filename

Tags: command-line, spotlight, filesystem

I have a ton of files - [TOSEC](http://www.tosecdev.org/) ROM sets - on my Mac (El Capitan) that have filenames suffixed with a tag in square brackets - for example

```
Manic Miner (1983)(Bug-Byte Software)[a]
Manic Miner (1983)(Software Projects)[a]
```

I'd like to search for these files, with the aim of moving and/or deleting them.

If I try to search for the files using Spotlight:

[image]

... no files are found.

If I try searching for them via Terminal:

```
ls *[a]*.*
```

... I get a list of all the files in the directory.

What's the best way of finding all files with `[a]` in the filename, and moving and/or deleting them? Is there a way to encapsulate the `[` and `]` so a Spotlight search will work?

Comment: I'd have a look at [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) on the app store, freeware. Very comprehensive search options, though no indexing, so it's slower than other methods

Comment: Thanks - definitely a useful tool, I can see it coming in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find and delete files that have `[a]` in the name you can use the following command in a Terminal:

```
find . -name "*\[a\]*" -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm
```

The above command will find and echo the `rm` command with the filenames containing `[a]`. The `echo` portion of the command line is added as a safety precaution. Run the command to see that you are okay with its output and then run it again without `echo` in the command line to actually delete the files the command outputs.

The shell treats the square brackets differently and as such they need to be escaped with a backslash `\` and why the output of `ls` was not what you wanted.

Comment: @KenD, Glad it worked for you. By the way the app mentioned by Tetsujin, EasyFind, is an excellent and handy app to have when you want to do some searching from a GUI versus the command line.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal, use `\` to escape any character:

```
ls *\[a\]*
```